# Validate each item in the array comparing with the rest of the elements in the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops, for-loop

I want to validate all the items in the array comparing with other items of the same array using some validation rules.

Like an item in an array cannot have an order date and delivery date overlapping other item's dates etc., etc., I have close to 10-15 validations that I need to verify by either looping or something that is more efficient.

I have a logic now to take an item and check against other ones in a loop but as the array size increases, this loop is taking long time to execute.

Is there a better way to redo this logic? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you find the item? By ID?

Comment: Yes, I have an ID element.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I thought your problem was that you were trying to find an element from one array in another array.

Comment: It would be hard to answer this as optimizing it can vary quite a lot depending on the actual validation logic. A good principle would be to leverage as much of the builtin `Array` functions (ie `map()`, `reduce()`, `filter()`, `includes()`, `every()`, `some()`, etc) as they are most optimized.